# (C++) My output .txt file has wierd spacing

Tags: c++

Heres what i mean. If you want the code, then here is the part that streams to the output file. I'm trying to calculate the integral of 2x-x^2. And then compare it to finding it using addition of trapezoid areas. [Here's what i mean by weird spacing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6OUvy.png)

additional text additional text additional text additional text additional text additional text additional text additional text additional text additional text additional text additional text additional text additional text additional text additional text additional text additional text additional text additional text additional text additional text additional text additional text additional text additional text

```
#include <iostream>

#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
double a, b, N = 10;
ifstream in_s("inYusupov.txt");
ofstream out_s("outYusupov.txt");

while (in_s >> a >> b)
{
    N = 10;
    //Для графика y= 2x-(x)^2
    double true_value = ((b*b) - (b*b*b) / 3) - ((a*a) - (a*a*a) / 3);
    out_s << "a=" << a << "\t" << "b=" << b << "\n";
    out_s << "True value=" << true_value << "\n" << "\n";

    while (N <= 100)
    {
        double h = (b - a) / N;
        double area = 0;

        //точки трапеции
        double coor_1 = a;
        double coor_2 = coor_1 + h;


        while (coor_1<b)
        {   //я выразил точки подставив их в y= 2x-(x)^2
            double y_1 = 2 * (coor_1)-(coor_1*coor_1);
            double y_2 = 2 * (coor_2)-(coor_2*coor_2);
            double pol_sum = (y_2 + y_1) / 2;

            // S трапеции - полусумма оснований на высоту. Высота - h, полусумма - (y_2 + y_1) / 2
            double s = pol_sum*h;
            area = area + s;
            coor_1 = coor_1 + h;
            coor_2 = coor_2 + h;

        }
        //в outYusupov.txt
        cout << N << "\t" << area << "\t" << (true_value - area) << "\n";
        out_s << N << "\t" << area << "\t" << (true_value - area) << "\n";
        N = N + 10;



    }

    out_s << "\n";

}
out_s.close();
cin.get();
return 0;
```

}

Comment: (Welcome to SO!) (What is all that `additional text`-business?) I see "standard" interpretation of "tabulator stop code"s: *move to next multiple of eight*. What *is* your question? (Please fix your code block: the lines from the first in main to the terminating `}` need to start with four more blanks.)

Answer (score 2):

You are suffering from incorrect use of tabulators. Amount of spaces added by tabulator depends or text viewing application settings and initial tab offset so adding them does not necessary make resulting document have proper columns. Use fixed-width printing instead:

```
<< ::std::setw(6) << N << ::std::setw(10) << area << ::std::setw(10) << (true_value - area) << "\n";
```